# Removing vbaProject.bin in XML not enough to save as xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, vba, zip

After exporting data into an Excel workbook with macros (xlsm), I run the macro and then remove the macro in order to be able to save the workbook as xlsx. For removing macros, I open the xlsm as zip archive (via C# ZipFile class), remove the entry "xl/vbaProject.bin" and remove a relation within "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels". Then I rename the file from xlsm to xlsx. That works fine so far but when I open the xlsx file in Excel, I get "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file", so there seems something to be missing in order to completely remove the vba code within the workbook. Can anyone help me here?

```
const string vbaProjectEntryName = "xl/vbaProject.bin"; // Contains the VBA code
const string relationsEntryName = "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels"; // Relation/Link to the vba project

using (var zip = ZipFile.Open(fileName, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var entry = zip.GetEntry(vbaProjectEntryName);
    if (entry != null)
    {
        entry.Delete();

        entry = zip.GetEntry(relationsEntryName);
        if (entry != null)
        {
            var contents = string.Empty;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
            {
                contents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var relationText = "<Relationship Id=\"rId6\" Type=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/vbaProject\" Target=\"vbaProject.bin\"/>";
            contents = contents.Replace(relationText, string.Empty);
            entry.Delete();
            entry = zip.CreateEntry(relationsEntryName);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(contents);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In "xl\_rels\workbook.xml.rels" there's an entry that refers to the vbaProject.bin. There are probably other conditions. What you need to do is manually Save As XLSX format, and then diff the XLSX vs XLSM

Comment: Why are you trying to manipulate the file like this? Why don't you just open the workbook in Excel and use `SaveAs` to save the workbook in the xlsx format? This could be done eg. by VBA or C# using the Excel API. That would be the proper way to go without manipulating the file. Also this way it cannot accidentally be corrupted.

Comment: Pᴇʜ: Because I didn't know how to programmatically answer the "functionality gets removed" question. Using excel.DisplayAlerts = false; did the trick, so I am going the proper way now. Thank you!

Comment: @IngoB Well, asking X while your actual issue is Y will (always) end up the wrong tree ;) To avoid this you might be interested in reading [What is the X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Pᴇʜ: Right. But I found it cool to modify the Excel that way ;) and I learned a bit about what's possible.